# Encoding/Decoding PDU 7bit septets GSM long messages

Tags: c#, encoding, gsm, pdu

I'm looking for Encoding/Decoding algorithm.
I have tried this:
http://codeproblem.hamaraquetta.com/articles/languages/81-net-framework/76-encoding-sms-in-pdu-format-in-net?showall=&start=1

and no luck. :(

Here is what I'm trying

This is the text:

```
This is a long text message greater than 160 characters. You can encode it to PDU format using the SMS-PDU lib for .NET, It also supports UCS-2 encoding, and special characters like { [ ] } are also supported. Its quite simple to use in your code.
```

From this text there should 2 messages encoded to `septets` and after I should be able to submit the message.

This is the result i get:
**Part 1:**

```
0041000C917952205197720000A00500033F0201A8E8F41C949E83C220F6DB7D06D1CB783AA85D9ECFC3E732E82C2F87E96539888E0EBB41311B0C344687E5E131BD2C9FBB40D9771D340EBB4165F7F84D2E83D27410FD0D8212AB20F35BDE0ED341F579DA7D06D1D165D0B4396D418955103B2D0699DF7290CB59A4B240493A28CC9EBF41F33A1CFE96D3E7A0EA70DA9281CAEEF19B9C769F59
```

**Part 2:**

```
0041000C917952205197720000690500033F020240613719348797C7E9301B344687E5E131BD2C9F83D8E97519B44181363CD0C607DAA4406179191466CFDFA0791D0E7FCBE965B20B94A4CF41F17A9A5E06CDD36D38BB0CA2BF41F57919947683F2EFBA1C347E93CB2E
```

this is doesn't work.

How do I solve this?

Btw: this is the phonenumber i know it's important.
+972502157927

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Library works completely correctly. ComposeLongSms() returns a string array of PDUs and you should send("submit" as you said) all these PDUs to your GSM modem like separate SMSes. Any concatenating won't work, you can notice that each PDU starts with the same part, which contains encoded additional information for outgoing SMS. You can verify your PDUs [here](http://www.diafaan.com/sms-tutorials/gsm-modem-tutorial/online-sms-pdu-decoder/)